# Report missing translation because of Xpath

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo

original report is this one and i want to override it with my new one.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_qweb">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
            <div class="page">
                <div>
```

i try to use

```
 <data>
          <template id="report_invoice_inherit" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_qweb">

        <xpath expr="div[@class='page']" position="replace">
```

but the problem that my new report not having translation in it. because it's missing

```
<t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
```

how can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `<t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />` is still in `report_invoice_qweb`, you haven't modified or removed that, so I guess that's not the problem. I mean that after your modifications the new account report will be like this:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_qweb">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
            <div class="page">  <!-- (YOUR CUSTOM div class="page") --> 
               ... your code ...
            </div>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I think that the issue is that you haven't exported the translation of your module to your language and the new content of the `<div class="page">` is not translated yet.

So the solution is going to *Settings > Translations > Import / Export > Export Translation*, choosing your module and your language and editing the generated `.po` file (or `.csv`) to translate the terms added by you.